# Lightning Locker is blocking HTMLScriptElement

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

I'm trying to inject a script into the lightning page by adding the JS Script into the pagebut i'm not able to see any Error or script in the page
from Locker Compatibility HTMLScriptElement element is Supported  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer

i'm using the following Script to append Script Element into the page

```
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.text = "Console.log("Test Create element Script");
                document.body.appendChild(script);
```

When the lightning locker is off Script work fine

Q: is there a workaround to add HTMLScriptElement into lightning page with lightning locker ON?

Answer (score 2):

If you were allowed to inject a script tag, you'd be able to circumvent Locker Service. For this reason, you're not allowed to do this. Use [ltng:require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation) or [loadScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-platform-resource-loader/documentation) to load scripts for use in your components.